# Tengo un problema con las dimensiones de pantalla en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout, android-drawerlayout

estoy desarrollando una app , pero nose como puedo hacer que esta se adapte a todas las pantallas de los telefonos existentes , si bien esta programada solo a layout que mi visor de android studio , en este caso el telefono de 4" por defecto , se ve aparentemente bien , pero si este es probado en otros dispositivos externos que no coinciden con la misma de mi proyecto android studio , se deforma , desde este punto , ya se pierde la apariencia , como hacer para que se adapte a todo tipo de pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez deberías empezar con algún tutorial o similar para tomar una idea general de como se hace. De esta manera, si en el futuro sigues teniendo alguna duda, tus dudas serán más específicas y por lo tanto más fáciles de responder.
Podrías empezar viendo estos 3 vídeos:
http://www.paredro.com/aprende-de-diseno-responsive-en-android-con-estos-3-videos/

Answer (score 1):

suponiendo que solo tienes el activity_main en tu carpeta layout, lo que tienes que hacer es:
Posicionarte en dicha carpeta (layout) pulsar el botón derecho del mouse y luego ir a New -> Layout resource file (y le das click ahí) 
Te enumero los pasos mejor.

**1)** Al abrirse la ventana de: New Resource File, donde dice: File name: ahí escribes activity_main, el mismo nombre de tu archivo que ya tienes creado por defecto en tu app.

**2)** sin cerrar la ventana donde has escrito en el File name: activity_main
fíjate que mas abajo dice: Available qualifiers:(en ese recuadro de opciones elige la opción "Size", tiene una flecha cruzada de esquina a esquina)

**3)** una vez que hayas elegido esa opción, entre medio de los dos recuadros tienes unas flechas parecidas a estas: >> (estas flechas sirven para agregar las diferentes opciones de tamaño a tu nuevo activity_main) Pulsa esas flechas y veras que te muestra a tu derecha las opciones de pantalla.

**4)** Una vez pulsada las flechas >> podrás ver que a tu derecha tienes en el área de Screen size: las opciones, Small, Normal, Large, X-Large.

- Para cada opción tienes que crear un archivo activity_main, quiero decir: No puedes agregar Small y Normal en el mismo archivo. Tienes que crear 4 activity_main para poder visualizar tu app en los diferentes tipos de pantalla.

*Espero haber sido de ayuda, un saludo.*